# How to implement __delitem__ method?

Tags: python, performance, doubly-linked-list

I would like to know the best way to go about fixing the **delitem** method body to improve efficiency, I'm getting an error that won't exit the loop.

```
    def __delitem__(self, idx):
        """Implements `del self[idx]`"""
        nidx = self._normalize_idx(idx)
        currNode = self.head.next
        if nidx >= len(self):
            raise IndexError
        for i in range(nidx+1, len(self)):
            self[i-1] = self[i]
        del self[len(self)-1]
```

Comment: As you actually note in the docstring, the `__delitem__` method *"Implements `del self[idx]`"*. Inside that method, you call `del self[len(self)-1]`. The recursion seems inevitable.

Comment: Deleting an item in a linked list involves redirecting the references in the node prior and next to the deleted node.  You should not need to call `del`, since the reference count should drop to zero.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend to remove the line

```
del self[self.length-1]
```

You should be able to leave this up to the garbage collector since this element should not be referenced anywhere else, as far as I can tell. It would then get deleted automatically.

Otherwise you'd call `__delitem__` infinitely often by calling `del` on `self` (which you've experienced already)

Comment: If I still run this test case after deleting the line I get an error saying 1 != 20  however I'm not sure where this 20 is coming from

Comment: I think this is a different issue, at least it comes from some later code in your test code